# How to install QtXlsx addon (On windows)

Tags: qt, installation

Good day. I need help installing [this](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter) module on my Qt.

There is a "readme" file that says the following:

> QtXlsx is a library that can read and write Excel files. It doesn't require Microsoft Excel and can be used in any platform that Qt5 supported. The library can be used to
>
> - Generate a new .xlsx file from scratch
> - Extract data from an existing .xlsx file
> - Edit an existing .xlsx file
>
> ### Getting Started
>
> ### Usage(1): Use Xlsx as Qt5's addon module
>
> Building the module
>
> > Note: Perl is needed in this step.
>
> - Download the source code.
> - Put the source code in any directory you like
> - Go to top directory of the project in a terminal and run
>
>   ```
>   qmake
>   make
>   make install
>   ```
> - The library, the header files, and others will be installed to your system.

The problem is... I can not find the command `make` on the terminal. `qmake` is fine, but when I use `make` this error message shows:

```
make is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

My OS is Windows 7 and I do have Perl installed.

---

EDIT 1:

I am using MinGW 5.3.0 32bit as a compiler.

Comment: You have to use a msvc commandline prompt, assuming you're using MSVC. Instead of `make`, you should invoke `nmake`.

Comment: I do not have MSVC. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: What compiler are you using, then? How did you install Qt? Why are you not telling us everything needed to diagnose the problem?

Comment: 1) I will edit my question with that information. 2) I can't remeber. But I don't use anything related to MSVC. 3) I can barely understand the problem on it self. I don't know the necessary informations for a diagnostic. Anything else i should edit in my question? other infos maybe?

Comment: Since you can run all of the steps from Qt Creator, why won't you do so? Then you don't need to know where Qt put the `make` utility. Otherwise, find `make.exe` in Qt's installation folder, and add its location to the global `PATH` environment variable and do the steps from the command line as you did so far.

Comment: You can open the project in Qt Creator. Once configured for the Qt kit you wish to use, to to the Project screen append a make step with `install`. Then build the project, and it will get installed as well.

Comment: I had no ideia it was possible within the Qt to install addon. I tried the steps above and i still got an error: " Failed to run: perl -w C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin\syncqt.pl -module QtXlsx -version 0.3.0 -outdir "C:/Andre/Qt Third-Parties/build-qtxlsx-Desktop_Qt_5_6_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug" C:/Andre/Qt Third-Parties/QtXlsxWriter-master". Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Is `perl` in your path? You don't need to ask about every little thing, try to understand what the error message means and proceed appropriately.

Comment: @KubaOber I once again apologise. I've never messed with addon modules and was going into it blind. Thanks for the support though. I will try messing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

After searching on many forums and GitHub issues, I've decided to give it another shot and do it cleanly.

Right now I'm using **Qt 5.9.1** and MinGW-32. that's all I had when I downloaded the library again.

### Before Installing

- **The module:** The [module](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter) is from [dbzhang800](https://github.com/dbzhang800) but the actor is no longer active. Also, the module compatibility with Qt 4.0+ is very limited. Luckly for us, there is another user who is maintaining the module on his own repository, [VSRonin](https://github.com/VSRonin). Even better is the fact that this fork is compatible with Qt 4.0+. [Here](https://github.com/VSRonin/QtXlsxWriter) is the link to VSRonin's version.
- **Prerequisites:** `Perl` is needed for the installation. Note that for me, `Strawberry Perl` didn't work. So I used `Active Perl` and I recommend doing the same. You can find it [here](https://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads). After installing, use the command `perl -v` to check the version. *perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread* is the one I used.
- **Environment Variables:** Make sure your PATH variable is set correctly. To check this, type `qmake -v`. If you can't find the command, you have two options:

  1. Open the Qt command prompt. This command prompt will use the correct path. Test it again by typing `qmake -v`.
  2. Set the environment variable yourself. [Here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) is a guide to how to set or change the PATH system variable.

### How to Install

1. Download QtXlsx from VSRonin.
2. Put the source code in any directory you like.
3. Go to top directory of the project in a terminal (cd path/to/your/project).
4. Type:

   `qmake`

   `mingw32-make`

   `mingw32-make install`

### Conclusion

Now to test if the installation worked, open a project and type this on the .pro:

`QT += xlsx`

Now compile it. If the compilation finishes, the module is installed.

Good coding :)